# TPL Parallel.For with long running tasks

Tags: .net, f#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am wanting to use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) in F# to execute many (>1000) long running tasks. Here is my current code:

```
Parallel.For(1, numberOfSets, fun j ->
    //Long running task here
    )
```

When I start this it appears that .NET initiates all of the tasks at once and bounces between  them constantly. What would be better is if it stayed on a task until it is done before moving to the next one. This would minimize the context switching.

Is there a way to provide a hint to the scheduler? I know that it is possible to provide hints but I cannot find clear examples or is the scheduler already smart about this and it's just my perception that there are too many context switches occuring. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a similar problem - using C# instead than F#, but the libraries are the same. The solution was to limit the degree of parallelism:

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16;
Parallel.For(0, n, parallelOptions, i => {
   . . . 
});
```

16 worked well for our tasks - you should experiment to see which value is better in your case.

Comment: Should the MaxDegreeOfParallelism depend on the number of cores on your machine?

Comment: @Wallhood: probably yes if the task is CPU-bound, if the task is IO-bound (file processing, access to a DB) probably not. In our case that value worked ok on 2/4 cores in normal situations, there was no real reason to try something more sophisticated - it is not a program that is likely to be run on a 16 core super-machine for example.

Comment: @MiMo: I have a 4 core machine and I set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 4 and it is working beautifully. The tasks are purely CPU-bound so minimizing the context switches really speeds it up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Wallhood instead of hard-coding the value, you can set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to `System.Environment.ProcessorCount`. You may need to divide the processor count by 2 to account for hyperthreading though.

Comment: @JackP.: Thanks! That was the next thing that I was going to look for.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, for a big number of tasks it's better to bound `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` linearly to `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Here is a similar code fragment to @Mimo's one in F# syntax:

```ml
let options = ParallelOptions()
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism <- Environment.ProcessorCount * 2

Parallel.For(0, n, options, 
             (fun i -> (* Long running task here *))) |> ignore
```

Since you're working with parallel programming in F#, please take a look at the excellent book ["Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx), particularly the chapter on ["Parallel Loops"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx). @Tomas has translated its samples to F# and they're available [here](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69940#814163).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the reference source, it appears the following piece of code determines the number of workers:

```
// initialize ranges with passed in loop arguments and expected number of workers 
int numExpectedWorkers = (parallelOptions.EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel == -1) ?
    Environment.ProcessorCount : 
    parallelOptions.EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel;
```

As far as I can tell, with the default task scheduler and default ParallelOptions this evaluates to `Environment.ProcessorCount`, so it's weird that you're getting a different behavior by specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to the processor count yourself. I suggest you debug to make sure there really is a difference (you could print the `Thread.ManagedThreadId` inside the long running task).

Comment: There was a substantial difference. When I specified the Max Concurrency it would only open one task at a time per core. When I didn't specify it, it would open all of the tasks at once. It may have only worked on one at a time but it did have them all open. I'm deducing this from the fact I start timers for each of the tasks. When I specified the parallelism the time for each task was the same. When I didn't the tasks could take a very long time to complete. What's going on underneath, I don't know but those were my observations.

Comment: Maybe the number of workers and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` are two different things? I confirm what @Wallhood says: whithout setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` when we had 1000's of tasks they seemengly all started in parallel and they were chocking the machine, the problem was fixed setting it to 16 (our task are not CPU but mostly database bound)